# Modifying multidimensional array at a specific index in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array A with shape: (10, 20, 3)
I want to modify index 2 of the third array for all the rows and columns.
I tried doing it this way:

```
A[:,:,2] += 100
```

This partly works but when I want to check if the value of each row and column at index 2 is higher than 200 I cannot unless I use two nested for loops. **This works, but it is not fast at all.**

This is what I have right now:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(20):
        if (A[i,j,2] + 100) > 200 :
            A[i,j,2] = 200
        else:
            A[i,j,2] += 100
```

I am looking for a more efficient and elegant way to accomplish this.

Comment: You write about "array" and "shape" and use `[:,:,2]` in your code. Are you using numpy arrays? Do you want your answer to be limited to regular Python or should it use numpy? By the way, your code example is elegant, since it is clear. Do you really need something faster?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I am using numpy arrays. I will edit that, sorry. I was thinking that it would be possible to do it with less lines of code and maybe faster using vectorization.

Comment: @Molina12, i'm not sure it'll help in this case but consider using `numba.jit(nopython=True)` on your for loop function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you want to add 100 to all the elements in the 2nd index of the 3rd dimension... but if the sum goes over 200, just make it 200.

A rule of thumb in NumPy is you ~never need loops. I think you can achieve what you want directly with indexing, eg:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.random.random((10, 20, 3))*200
>>> A[...,2] += 100
>>> A[...,2][A[...,2] > 200] = 200
array([[[ 131.94487476,   57.20338449,  200.        ],
        [  22.7506817 ,  145.74740259,  200.        ],
        [  15.44748999,  180.55442849,  189.48182561],
        [ 160.35622709,    2.37465206,  183.96627351],
        [  67.79103218,   70.28339315,  108.90041475],
        [ 129.33682572,  102.6764913 ,  200.        ],
        .
        .
        .
```

Where `A[...,2]` is just another way of saying the second index (third element) in the last dimension.